# How to add style and script subdirectories to a lift project

Tags: lift

How can I add subdirectories to a lift project (builing with SBT) to better organise the project.

Currently, The only way I can cusomise the style is to add css files to the webapp root directory, and I'm guessing I'm going to have a similar problem with any custom js script files. So I'm going to have a lot of .js and .css files mixing around with a bunch of html files as well.

I've tried Lift Rules in the Boot.scala file
eg LiftRules.fixCSS("static" :: "style" :: Nil, Empty) but this doesn't seem to work, I keep on getting "/default.css returned 404"

and I've tried adding the directory to the static folder as well.

I'm used to a java/jsp/servlet approach where I would have webapp/style and webapp/script subdirectories that I could access from any html/.jsp files pretty much directly. Is this the wrong idea in Lift?

Comment: The problem was caused by not understanding how the Lift framework worked. I was trying to access the subfolders in the content html head section, not the html that was surrounding the content. (Called with the lift:surround tag) So of course the style sheets and scripts where not being included.

Answer (score 0):

Lift is no different to a regular JSP application when it comes to serving static files. Just make whatever directory you want within src/main/webapp and that will be publicly available. You only need to make additions to the Boot w/r/t to LiftRules when you wish to write a plugin for Lift or make those static files in some way redistributable outside your own application (which you don't want to do by the sounds of it).